# windows command to find combination of child tags in parent tag in xml file

Tags: xml, string, windows, command, findstr

Below is my sample xml

```
<parent1>
<child1>test1</child1>
<child2>test2</child2>
<child3>test3</child3>
</parent1>

<parent2>
<child1>test1</child1>
<child2>test2</child2>
<child3>test3</child3>
</parent2>

<parent3>
<child1>test1</child1>
<child2>test2</child2>
<child3>test3</child3>
</parent3>
```

Now I want to find count of occurrence for below combination

```
 <child1>test1</child1>
 <child3>test3</child3>
```

I tried below command

```html
findstr /R /c:"<child1>test1</child1>.*<child3>test3</child3>*" test.xml
```

but it expects both child1 and child3 in single line.

as here it is in different lines, it is not giving any count.

Can someone please help me to find out window command to fulfill this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to search for either `<child1>test1</child1>` or `<child3>test3</child3>`:

```
@echo off

findstr /n /r /c:"<child1>test1</child1>" /c:"<child3>test3</child3>" data4.xml | find /c ":"
```

With the parameter `/C` of  `find` you can get the number of results.